# How to convert XML to JSON using only Jackson?

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

I am getting a response from server as XML. But I need to display this in JSON format.

Is there any way to convert it without any third party API? I used Jackson but for this I need to create POJO.

The response from server is like this:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<errors><error><status>400</status><message>The field 'quantity' is invalid.</message><details><invalid_reason>The quantity specified is greater than the quantity of the product that is available to ship.</invalid_reason><available_quantity>0</available_quantity><order_product_id>12525</order_product_id></details></error></errors>
```

Comment: Is there any chance that that server also supports `application/json`?

Comment: Jackson has an XML converter as well, by the way

Comment: Yes.. When i post like this :                                                            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(aobj, ContentType.create("application/json")));
response = httpclient.execute(target, httpPost);                                          I am getting success or failure response as in xml format form server.

Comment: @cricket_007 But i dont want to create the pojo class for that .. for success it sent me success message and in  failure it sent me error message so.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is really off-topic. The OP didn't ask us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource. They asked if there is any way to convert a XML to JSON *without any third party API*.

Comment: Note: Jackson 2.12 has significantly improved support for XML reading into POJOs and `JsonNode` -- see https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-2-12-improved-xml-b9487889a23f -- which does allow conversion between XML and JSON using `JsonNode` (or `java.lang.Object`) as intermediate value.

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.xmlToJson(xml).

Answer (score 34):

### Using Jackson 2.x

You can do that with Jackson and no POJOs are required for that:

```java
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
             "<errors>\n" +
             "  <error>\n" +
             "    <status>400</status>\n" +
             "    <message>The field 'quantity' is invalid.</message>\n" +
             "    <details>\n" +
             "      <invalid_reason>The quantity specified is greater than the quantity of the product that is available to ship.</invalid_reason>\n" +
             "      <available_quantity>0</available_quantity>\n" +
             "      <order_product_id>12525</order_product_id>\n" +
             "    </details>\n" +
             "  </error>\n" +
             "</errors>";

XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
JsonNode node = xmlMapper.readTree(xml.getBytes());

ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(node);
```

The following dependencies are required:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Be aware of the `XmlMapper` limitations stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml):

> **Tree Model is only supported in limited fashion:** specifically, Java arrays and `Collections` can be written, but can not be read, since it is not possible to distinguish Arrays and Objects without additional information.

As nicely highlighted by the [Jackson author in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493173/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-using-only-jackson/39493394?noredirect=1#comment120312236_39493394), **Jackson 2.12** finally [improved XML handling](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-2-12-improved-xml-b9487889a23f), so that duplicates are preserved **if** using `JsonNode` or `Object` as target types.

### Using JSON.org

You also can do it with JSON.org:

```java
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
             "<errors>\n" +
             "  <error>\n" +
             "    <status>400</status>\n" +
             "    <message>The field 'quantity' is invalid.</message>\n" +
             "    <details>\n" +
             "      <invalid_reason>The quantity specified is greater than the quantity of the product that is available to ship.</invalid_reason>\n" +
             "      <available_quantity>0</available_quantity>\n" +
             "      <order_product_id>12525</order_product_id>\n" +
             "    </details>\n" +
             "  </error>\n" +
             "</errors>";

String json = XML.toJSONObject(xml).toString();
```

The following dependency is required:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160810</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you @cassio .But  we are using jackson1.7 and I am not seeing there is XMLMapper in this jar. do I need extra jar for XMLMappper too.

Comment: @samunp I'm not sure if you'll be able to do it with Jackson 1.x. I updated my answer with an alternative. It requires an external dependency though.

Comment: Thank you for posting the nice answer. In my project I are using jackson-all-1.7.X and there is no xmlMapper

Comment: @samunp Just letting you know, the XML support for Jackson 2.x is released as a separated artifact. In other words, even when you use Jackson 2.x, you will need to include the `jackson-dataformat-xml` dependency if you want to use the `XmlMapper`.

Comment: This is one of the only decently coherent answers I've ever seen on this site regarding MIME conversion.  Thank you.

Comment: jackson is mixing tag attributes and values: having <param name="1">val1</param><param name="2">val2</param> ends with {"param":{"name":"2", "":"val2"}} while org.json.json is doing <param name="1">val1</param><param name="2">val2</param> correctly as { "param":{"1":"val1","2":"val2"}}

Comment: BIG WARNING with the Jackson option is that XML often has duplicate keys and when Jackson converts that XML with duplicate keys to JSON, they will get overwritten.

Comment: Above warnings are legit but note that Jackson 2.12 finally improved handling (see https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-2-12-improved-xml-b9487889a23f) so that duplicates are preserved IF using `JsonNode` or `Object` as target types.

Comment: Nice one, @StaxMan! I've just added this note to my answer. Thanks for the comment and for all work on Jackson.

Answer (score 27):

I know that I am too late for an answer here. But I am writing this for the new guys who stumbled upon this question and thinking to use @Cassio's answer.

The problem of using `XmlMpper` to de-serialize to a `JsonNode` is that, when there are multiple elements with the same name at the same level, then it will replace the previous one with the new one and end up with data loss. Usually, we've to add this to an array. To tackle this problem, we can override the `_handleDuplicateField()` method of the `JsonNodeDeserializer` class. Enough talking. Let's see the code

```
public class DuplicateToArrayJsonNodeDeserializer extends JsonNodeDeserializer {

    @Override
    protected void _handleDuplicateField(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt, 
        JsonNodeFactory nodeFactory,String fieldName, ObjectNode objectNode,
        JsonNode oldValue, JsonNode newValue) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ArrayNode node;
        if(oldValue instanceof ArrayNode){
            node = (ArrayNode) oldValue;
            node.add(newValue);
        } else {
            node = nodeFactory.arrayNode();
            node.add(oldValue);
            node.add(newValue);
        }
        objectNode.set(fieldName, node);
    }
}
```

Since we've overridden the default deserializer, we also need to register this in the `XmlMapper` to make it work.

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(
    JsonNode.class, 
    new DuplicateToArrayJsonNodeDeserializer()
));
JsonNode node = xmlMapper.readTree(payLoad);
```

Comment: Awesome answer!

Comment: Very good! Also note that as of Jackson 2.12 above is done by XML module too (see https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-2-12-improved-xml-b9487889a23f)

Comment: Great answer, good works for me!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to convert xml to json without using any third party API?

If you are being practical, no there isn't.

The step of parsing the XML can be performed using APIs that are part of Java SE.  However going from the parsed XML (e.g. a DOM) to JSON requires a JSON support library, and Java SE does not include one.

(In theory you *could* write such a library yourself, but what is the point of doing that?)

---

> I used Jackson but for this I need to create POJO.

@Cassio points out that Jackson allows you to do this translation without writing POJOs.  Alternatively, look at other (3rd-party) JSON APIs for Java; see http://www.json.org for a list of alternatives.  Some of the simpler ones don't involve defining POJOs

Answer (score 3):

Using jackson

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonUtil {

    private static XmlMapper XML_MAPPER = new XmlMapper();
    private static ObjectMapper JSON_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    public static ObjectMapper getJsonMapper(){
        return JSON_MAPPER;
    }

    public static XmlMapper getXmlMapper(){
        return XML_MAPPER;
    }

    public static String xmlToJson(String xml){
        try {
            return getJsonMapper().writeValueAsString(getXmlMapper().readTree(xml));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the author of Jackson, [Jackson 2.12 is able to read XML with readTree even with duplicate elements](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/187#issuecomment-865132191):

> Note: Jackson version 2.12 DOES allow reading of duplicate elements with readTree().
> (also works for nominal type of java.lang.Object, so-called "untyped" binding).

So from Jackson 2.12 on, you can just use

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
JsonNode node = xmlMapper.readTree(xml.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.src.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import net.sf.json.JSON;
import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer;

public class JSONConverter {
    private static URL url = null;
    private static InputStream input = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        try {
            url = JSONConverter.class.getClassLoader().getResource("sampleXmlFilePath.xml");
            input = url.openStream();
            String xmlData = IOUtils.toString(input);

            XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
            JSON json = xmlSerializer.read(xmlData);
            System.out.println("JSON format : " + json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just followed **cassiomolin** steps. I have faced below exception while using the jackson 2.x libraries.

```
Cannot create XMLStreamReader or XMLEventReader from a org.codehaus.stax2.io.Stax2ByteArraySource
```

If you also face the above exception. Add the below code to fix the issue. Then you can able to see the converted JSON without the namespace.

```
JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(module);
```

**Tips :** 
If you want to convert the XML without the namespace then use jackson library. Dont go for org.json libs. It doesnt support this use case.