# Jackson - convert JsonNode to xml

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

I want to convert Jackson `JsonNode` to `xml`.

There are reversed solutions like [xml-to-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493173/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-using-only-jackson).

My JsonNode:

```
//String to JsonNode
JsonNode node = m_mapper.readTree(responseString.toString());
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you check this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977979/converting-json-to-xml-in-java

Comment: I was looking for `JsonNode`(jackson) object solutions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63561066/1485527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this solution :

```
  String responseString = "{\"name\":\"FOO\",\"bar\":{\"id\":42}}";
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(responseString.getBytes());

     ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
     String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(node);
      System.out.println(xml);
```

output :

```
<ObjectNode xmlns=""><name>FOO</name><bar><id>42</id></bar></ObjectNode>
```

Comment: Well I was not looking for a solution that converts json to Class.

Comment: no this solution it allows to convert json to pojo and convert this pojo to xml .

Comment: But I don't have or need POJO just json to xml.

Comment: Trying and posting the result.