# All element names and values in a JSON

Tags: java, json, xml, comparison

I'm trying to fetch all the element names and values from a JSON.
Basically, I will be getting a JSON response and need to compare it to an XML response. The approach I have decided on for now is to get all element names and values from both the JSON and the XML, and then store them in separate lists. Finally, I will just compare the lists.

**Q1. Is there a better way to do what I am planning? (Compare JSON to XML)**

If no,
I'm facing some troubles while doing this. My JSON is a nested JSON and I need to fetch the values of ALL elements and their names. However, using the JSON, I am able to get only the outermost element. I need this fetch to be dynamic since I want to re-use the same code later for other similar comparisons

`(Using a sample XML I found in another answer on StackOverflow)`

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder;
import java. util.ArrayList;
import java. util.Iterator
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

xml = """
{
"master": {
   "node": "xyz", 
   "files": [{"type": "modified", "file": "test.txt"}]
   }, 
"testbranch2": {
   "node": "abc", 
   "files": [{"type": "modified", "file": "test.txt"}] 
   }, 
"testbranch": {
   "node": "xxx", 
   "files": [{"type": "modified", "file": "test.txt"}], 
   }
}
"""

def json = new JSONObject(xml);
def test = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json.toString())
log.info test.keySet() 
log.info test.Outer.keySet()
```

The `json.keys()` only manages to get the outermost key, and not all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use jackson to convert xml to json / JsonNode and then easily compare to any level you want.

See link below to see how to convert xml to json.
[How to convert XML to JSON using only Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493173/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-using-only-jackson)