# Jackson - Start from nested element

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

How can I read the XML from nested element.

Example:

```
<main>
    <child>
        <child2>
            <child3>
                <user>
                    <name>John</name>
                </user>
                <user>
                    <name>Doe</name>
                </user>
            </child3>
        </child2>
    <child1>
</main>
```

Now, I need to construct the user objects from this XML using Jackson. Basically I'm interested from child3 element. I don't want to create main, child1, child2 classes. Directly I want to read from child3. How can I achieve this? Please help

Comment: Why don't you parse this XML as DOM and take out child3 and pass that to other function to construct object from dom

Comment: @sonus21 can you give a sample snippet on how to take out child3?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try reading them in MAP class like below,

```
 XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
 Map<String,Object> map = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Map.class);
 Map<String,Object> child1 = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("child1");
 Map<String,Object> child2 = (Map<String, Object>) child1.get("child2");
 Map<String,Object> child3 = (Map<String, Object>) child2.get("child3");
```

Child3 Map  will only contain the data.
You will also need to import below maven library to use XMLMapper

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Another way would be to use JSONNode and then finally deserialize it into child3 object. as shown below,

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper(); //To convert JSON to object
JsonNode  map = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, JsonNode.class);
JsonNode child1 = map.get("child1");
JsonNode child2 = child1.get("child2");
JsonNode child3 = child2.get("child3");
Child3 child3 = jsonMapper.readValue(child3.toString(),Child3.class);
```

Comment: But, these two will give the JSON instead of XML. Because of this 
```xmlMapper.readValue(child3.toString(),Child3.class)``` is failing with an error: ```Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'```

Comment: Oh yes, you need to use ObjectMapper to convert JSON to Child3 Object. Have modifed the answer above

Comment: getting an error ```Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token```. Can you please help on this?

Comment: looks like Jackson XML mapper has issues while dealing with arrays or tags with similar names in the XML. It replaces the previous one with last one. Please see this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493173/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-using-only-jackson

Comment: There is solution as well in that thread on how to handle the duplicate(multiple) elements in the XML